# Mac OS X Sandbox and Disk Arbitration

Tags: macos, sandbox, diskarbitration

There doesn't seem to be an entitlement for use of the DVD drive when you sandbox your app.

Has anyone come up with a way to access it, specifically with the disk arbitration notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Disc recording should "just work" with no entitlement.  What OS version are you running on?